# Water at temperature of 4° C

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, density, molecules

We know that the density of  of water at $4°\rm C$ is maximum $1\rm\: g/cm³$. But how is it possible??

Suppose I have $1kg$ of water at $4°\rm C$ .So it's density is $1\rm\: g/cm³$. But what if the temperature is lower than $4°\rm C$? The volume should decrease and since  the mass is not disturbed, the density should rise up. But again it doesn't happen.

So why the density of water is maximum at $4°\rm C$? What is special at this temperature?

**Note**: I read the related question but I wasn't fully satisfied with the answer because my question was:

> - Why does it happen?
> - Why is the gap increased between molecules in that suggested question ?

It answered the example taken above (and thanks for that), but my question is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any relevance between phase diagram and energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/550010/is-there-any-relevance-between-phase-diagram-and-energy)

Comment: You write "But what if the temperature is lower than 4°C? The volume should decrease .." Why you say so?

Comment: Related on Chemistry: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/why-is-density-of-water-maximum-at-4-degree-celsius/105390#105390 (full disclosure, my answer).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that ice (or at least ice-I$_h$, which is what happens just below 0$^\circ$C at one atmosphere) is less dense than liquid water. You have experienced this when you had iced water at a meal and the solid cubes floated rather than sank in the liquid.

As the temperature of water approaches 0$^\circ$C from above, ice-like bonds between water molecules begin to compete with water-like bonds between water molecules, even though the water-like bonds are energetically favored above the freezing temperature. The mean distance between water molecules is larger in the ice-like interaction than in the liquid-like interaction. So as the temperature approaches 0$^\circ$C, the linear-ish behavior of the liquid-type bond distance with temperature is washed out by the increased prevalence of the solid-type bond.

Predicting that the minimum density should occur at $+4^\circ$C, rather than at 2$^\circ$ or 10$^\circ$, requires a calculation which is more complicated than I'm willing to put into this answer.